# BindIPEndPointDelegate not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

When I try BindIPEndPointDelegate, it seems to just go through the default IP address instead of the specified one. I tested this by trying a down port. `selint` is a network interface.

Here is my code:

```
testagainbutton.Text = "Fetching...";
            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requrl);
            req.Timeout = 10000;
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = (s, e, c) =>
            {
                return new IPEndPoint(getipaddress(selint), 0);
            };
            
            res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: How are you checking what it's doing, are you using Wireshark? Note that a proxy (even an internal one like Fiddler) may interfere with what you are trying to do. "I tested this by trying a down port" what does that mean?

Comment: @Charlieface I tested the function purposefully on a port that shouldn't be able to fetch requests, like a Bluetooth port, or a LAN network that's labeled as down.

Comment: Well what happens if you use a normal live port? Check with Wireshark what it's doing